# Why does hyperref/hpdftex.def v6.81u cause an error for me?

Tags: hyperref, errors

Background information: I'm using TeXlive 2010 (on ArchLinux x86_64, though installed through TUG/CTAN, not from the Arch repos). I update my system with tlmgr daily. All was well until today, perhaps having something to do with the most recent updates, and v6.81u of the hyperref package in particular (and the file hpdftex.def). Now, even this simple document:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \begin{document}
  Hello world.
  \end{document}
```

throws the following error:

```
  (/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
  File: hpdftex.def 2010/11/22 v6.81u Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
  /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def:35: Undefined
   control sequence.
  \pdf@ifdraftmode ->\ifnum \pdf@draftmode 
                                           =\ltx@one \expandafter \ltx@firstof...
  l.35 \pdf@ifdraftmode
                       {%
  The control sequence at the end of the top line
  of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
  misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
  spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
  and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Has anyone else had this problem? Is it a package version incompatibility? Here's what I get if I add \listfiles to the beginning of the code.

```
  *File List*
   article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  hyperref.sty    2010/11/22 v6.81u Hypertext links for LaTeX
   ltxcmds.sty    2010/04/26 v1.7 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
     ifpdf.sty    2010/01/28 v2.1 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  pdftexcmds.sty    2010/04/01 v0.9 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
  infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
  ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
    keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
  kvsetkeys.sty    2010/03/01 v1.9 Key value parser (HO)
  etexcmds.sty    2010/01/28 v1.3 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
  pdfescape.sty    2010/03/01 v1.9 Provides hex, PDF name and string conversions 
  (HO)
    ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
   ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
   hycolor.sty    2009/12/12 v1.6 Color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  xcolor-patch.sty    2009/12/12 xcolor patch
  letltxmacro.sty    2008/06/24 v1.3 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
  kvoptions.sty    2010/02/22 v3.7 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
    pd1enc.def    2010/11/22 v6.81u Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
   intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
  hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
       url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
    bitset.sty    2007/09/28 v1.0 Data type bit set (HO)
  bigintcalc.sty    2007/11/11 v1.1 Expandable big integer calculations (HO)
  atbegshi.sty    2010/03/25 v1.12 At begin shipout hook (HO)
   hpdftex.def    2010/11/22 v6.81u Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
  atveryend.sty    2010/03/24 v1.5 Hooks at very end of document (HO)
  rerunfilecheck.sty    2010/03/16 v1.6 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
  uniquecounter.sty    2009/12/18 v1.1 Provides unlimited unique counter (HO)
   nameref.sty    2010/04/30 v2.40 Cross-referencing by name of section
  refcount.sty    2008/08/11 v3.1 Data extraction from references (HO)
  gettitlestring.sty    2009/12/18 v1.3 Cleanup title references (HO)
   scratch.out
   scratch.out
   ***********
```

I'd be happy to upload the full log if anyone thinks it will help.

Comment: I get exactly the same, but I don't know how to update the file. How did you do it? (I'm on windows).

Comment: @Paul: If you've got a question, then you should ask it in a new post. Please do this with the "Ask Question" link. In your new question link to this one.

Comment: @Paul: This is not an answer but is more of a comment, or perhaps a separate question. I assume you use MiKTeX (as you are windows), in which case you'll need to use the update program once the fix is incorporated into MiKTeX.

Comment: nvm, I've been able to update it manually from http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/ 
For some reason, my texlive distribution tlmgr thought I had 6.81t installed and that this was the latest version so I couldn't update that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for raising the alarm, but I just upgraded again, and the problem seems to be fixed with version v6.81v. Still, word to the wise: watch out for v6.81u.

To be specific:

`hyperref.sty    2010/11/26 v6.81v Hypertext links for LaTeX`

and

`hpdftex.def    2010/11/26 v6.81v Hyperref driver for pdfTeX`

work fine, but v6.81u dated 2010/11/22 does not (for me anyway).